# X11 application not responding in Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, x11

I'm using **Ubuntu** *(Gnome)* and sometimes I receive the message

> “YourApp” is not responding.
>
> You may choose to wait a short while for it to continue or force the application to quit entirely.

although the app was responding just fine.

Is there an event that needs to be handled in `X11` to prevent the above message? Something like a `WM_PING` or the like

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be processing the event queue (regularly) in order for your application to not be deemed 'not responding'.